# Main page interface changed

Tags: support, user-interface, mobile-web

Recently my interface changed from

[image: original interface]

to

[image: new interface]

Is this something that is supposed to happen? Is it possible to get back the first one since it looks better? (Or at least it looks better for me.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the mobile interface. There should be a link that says "full site" at the bottom of the page to switch back to the desktop interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me it seems like you've been switched to the "mobile interface". At the bottom of every page there should be a link to the "full site":

[image: full site link in mobile interface]

Click on it to return to the usual interface.